# Get description when clicked on list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, i have a table, consisting of one tr and two td`s. In one td there is a list of users, in a second one, there is description, for each one.

```
      <tr>
        <td className='influencers'>
          <ul className='influencers-list'>
            {this.state.influencers.map(influencer =>
              <li key = {influencer.id}
                  className = 'influencers-list-item'
                  onClick={this.handleActive}
                  id = {influencer.id}>
                <p className='influencers-list-name'>{influencer.name}</p>
                <p className='influencers-list-data'>{influencer.created_at}</p>
                <p className='influencers-list-notes' >Notes</p>
              </li>)}
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div className = {`to-dont-list__description`}>
            {this.state.influencers.map(influencer =>
              <div key = {influencer.id}  id={influencer.id}>
                <div>
                  <p className = 'to-dont-list__data'>{influencer.created_at}</p>
                  <img src = {influencer.image} className = 'to-dont-list__img'/>
                  <p className='to-dont-list__name'>{influencer.name}</p>
                  <p className='to-dont-list__quote'>{influencer.bio}</p>
                </div>
                <ul>
                  {/*{this.state.influencers.map(influencer =>*/}
                    {/*<li key={influencer.id}>*/}
                      {/*<p><span>{influencer.toDont.id}</span>{influencer.toDont.rule}</p>*/}
                    {/*</li>     */}
                  {/*)}*/}
                </ul>
              </div>)}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

currently, i need to display the user description of the one thats clicked. How do i achieve that? because what i can do now is when clicked on any user in the list, only getting the 1st one to display.

Comment: What you can do is set the state for the active influencer and filter the other array based on the influencer state and display the result in second td using map.

Comment: @YashThakur, the data is a json, received from api, won't every click on the influencer trigger the state change, leading to the same problem i have now?

Comment: Please post the onClick handler

Comment: @Rahamin, nothing there yet, just got it for it to be there

Comment: You write "because what i can do now is when clicked on any user in the list, only getting the 1st one to display", so I understood that something happens when you click, in the onClick handler's code..

Are you saying that you didn't write the handler yet and you want advice about how to write it?

Comment: @Rahamin, exactly, while trying to achieve that, the only thing i achieved was the following, you mentioned before. and now i need to get advice about writing the one i need

Comment: Please see below

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood what you are looking for...
If I did, I would try the following:

```
onClick={() => this.handleActive.bind(this)(influencer)}
```

and

```
handleActive() {
  // get the description (not sure where from, but you should know)
  // I assume that newDescription has set with this value
  const inf = {...influencer, description: newDescription);
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    influencers: [...prevState.influencers, influencer]
  }));
}
```

Comment: description is the one in the second td, you can see it in snipet, i cant really tell what you are doing there, could you explain please?